# iPhone: Hide Keyboard on App Did Enter Background or View Did Disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, resignfirstresponder

I have a UISearchBar which when clicked, shows the keyboard.
However if the user presses the home button while the keyboard is shown and then goes back into the app, the keyboard is still visible.
How can I hide th keyboard when the app closes/enters background?

I've tried the following in viewDidDisappear:

```
[eventSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

[eventSearchBar endEditing:YES];
```

I've also tried this in the delegate in appDidEnterBackground:

```
[self.rootController.navigationController.view endEditing:YES];
```

None of these worked.

Comment: Have you tried it in willEnterBackground?

Comment: I don't think there is a willEnterBackground method

Comment: There is a `applicationWillResignActive:` method. Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks, I tried resignFirstResponder and endEditing in this method but still no luck, is rootController.navigationController.view the correct way to be calling it?

Comment: by the way rootController is of type TabBarController

Comment: Did you try `searchDisplayController.active = NO;` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can do this in appDelegate....

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.window endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is not called when the app goes into background.

Comment: That is probably a matter of taste. I prefer to do this locally in the view controller that it applies to.

Comment: This is the only solution of your problem....because neither viewwillapper nor viewwilldisapper called when app is minimize...it you want to do this then you have to do this in applicationDidEnterBackground method..

Comment: or you have to access your view in applicationDidEnterBackground...and then you can do [self.view endEditing:YES];...

Comment: There is another solution (see my answer).

Comment: if you can do this in one line then why to write huge of code...?

Comment: As I said, it is a matter of taste. You might have several loaded view controllers and each of them has to perform some cleanup when the app goes into background (stop editing, stop downloading etc.). - But we don't have to argue. We both presented a solution and that's fine. - And I will not respond by downvoting your answer.

Comment: PUT THIS METHOD IN YOUR APPDELEGATE.M

Comment: It can be put in applicationWillResignActive.

Answer (score 7):

Swift version of this:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    window?.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your view controller, for example in the init method, register for the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(willResignActive:)
    name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
    object:nil];
```

When the app goes into background, make the search display controller inactive. This removes the focus from the search field and hides the keyboard:

```
- (void)willResignActive:(NSNotification *)note
{
    self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;

    // Alternatively, if you only want to hide the keyboard:
    // [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And don't forget to remove the observer in the dealloc method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
    name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
    object:nil];
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it is isolated only to the view in question.

Comment: @dangytaggart: Yes, that's what I think. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Solution in swift 3.2 Version

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideTextField), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func hideTextField(){
        eventSearchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to put window?.endEditing(true) in applicationWillResignActive on AppDelegate:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    window?.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had all standard methods fail on my sporadically. So far this is the only way I've gotten solid results.

In topmost controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willResignActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) willResignActiveNotification:(NSNotification*) vNotification {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    [self setEditing:NO];
}
```

There is an odd case where a text field will no longer respond to `resignFirstResponder` or `endEditing` but still has keyboard up.